# Get full inspect element code from a webpage with python3

Tags: python, python-requests, python-3.6

I was trying to get the loaded html after running js code from a webpage, the same as it is shown in "inspect element". But it is not giving the correct result.
I tried to do the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver

import requests


url = 'xxx'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)

# This will get the initial html - before javascript
html1 = driver.page_source

# This will get the html after on-load javascript
html2 = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.innerHTML;")

print(html1)
print('\n\n')
print(html2)
```

I want to get the full code from inspect element (html2 in this case). I discovered that this attempt is getting the information from the page before it is fully loaded. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the data you need is present on the page

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

This will wait for the element whose id equals [ID_OF_ELEMENT].

```
timeout = 5

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, '[ID_OF_ELEMENT]')))
    #Page ready
except TimeoutException:
    #Timeout
```